# Number of cyclic subgroups order $p^2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $$G={ {\left \langle a \right \rangle}_{p} \times {\left \langle b \right \rangle}_{p} \times {\left \langle c \right \rangle}_{p^2}} \cong \mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_{p^2} \text{,  $p$ is prime}$$
There are $p^3-1$ elements with order $p$, $p^2(p^2-p)$ elements with order $p^2$.

So my questions are:

1. How many **cyclic** subgroups order $p^2$ (like $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}, \text{ not } \mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$) are in $G$?
   (As i know, number of **all** subgroups order $p^2$ in G are $2p^2+p+1$)
2. How many subgroups order $p$ are in $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lemma:** Let $n$ be number of the elements of order $m$ then there are $$\dfrac{n}{\phi(m)}$$ cylic subgroup of order $m$.

By the lemma, There are $\dfrac{p^2(p^2-p)}{\phi(p^2)}=p^2$ cyclic subgroup of order $p^2$.

I left the second question to you.