# Number of elements of order $p$ in product of $\mathbb{Z}_{p^a} \times \mathbb{Z}_{q^b} \times \mathbb{Z}_{r^{c}}$

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

After seeing this post [Number of cyclic subgroups order $p^2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1139730/number-of-cyclic-subgroups-order-p2-in-mathbbz-p-times-mathbbz-p-tim)
I have following questions.

Let $G \simeq \mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_q \times \mathbb{Z}_r$ where $p,q,r$ are primes. Then how many elements of order $p$, order $q$, and order $r$?

And what if I extend this $p,q,r$ to $p^{a}, q^{b}, r^{c}$?

Comment: Are $p$, $q$, and $r$ pairwise distinct?

Comment: Your title and post ask different questions.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, Thanks for notification, I edit the title!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will note that your subject line currently asks about *subgroups*, but your post asks about *elements*. Those are different counts. I will answer the question in the post.

If $p$, $q$, and $r$ are pairwise distinct, then $\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_q\times\mathbb{Z}_r$ is cyclic of order $pqr$, and hence has a unique subgroup of any order dividing $pqr$; so it has exactly $p-1$ elements of order $p$, $q-1$ elements of order $q$, and $r-1$ elements of order $r$.

The same is true if we take $p^a$, $q^b$, and $r^c$, for the same reason.

If two of the primes are equal and the third distinct, then we have, say, $\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_r$. There are exactly $r-1$ elements of order $r$, and $p^2-1$ elements of order $p$. If you take $\mathbb{Z}_{p^a}\times\mathbb{Z}_{p^b}\times\mathbb{Z}_{r^c}$, it’s the same answer.

If all primes are the same, and you have $\mathbb{Z}_{p^a}\times\mathbb{Z}_{p^b}\times\mathbb{Z}_{p^c}$. Each factor has exactly $p$ elements of exponent $p$, and an element of the whole thing is of order $p$ if and only if every coordinate is of exponent $p$ and at least one is of order $p$. That gives you $p^3-1$ elements of order $p$.

Comment: For pariwise distinct case, how one know there are exactly $p-1$ element of order $p$, and similarly for $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_r$, how one can know there are $p^2-1$ elements of order $p$? 

It seems $-1$ comes from identity am I right?

Comment: @phy_math: In a cyclic group of order $pqr$ there is one and only one subgroup of order $p$, which contains $p-1$ elements of order $p$. So every element of order $p$ is one of those $p-1$ elements. In the second case, you are just counting elements in $\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_p$ that are not trivial, since every element is of exponent $p$.